# What is different from "request.resource.auth" vs "request.auth" in Firestore security setting rule?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Today, I'm reading about Firestore security rule, 
I see to case using to check authentication rule with **"request.resource.auth"** and **"request.auth"**.
And I wonder what is different from them ? 
Here are about these example:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow any logged in user to view the public employee data
    match /employees/{emp_id} {
      allow read: if request.resource.auth != null
      // Allow only users with the custom auth claim of "Finance" to view
      // the employee's financial data
      match /private/finances {
        allow read: if request.resource.auth &&
          request.resource.auth.token.role == 'Finance'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow the user to access documents in the "cities" collection
    // only if they are authenticated.
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The firestore security example you're referring to with "request.resource.auth" is a custom authentication rule. Basically, it's not part of firestore, it's a field in the request's resource called "auth" that is being used to provide additional identification.
May I ask what language you're reading this in? I usually read the docs in English but when I have changed the language (or, more precisely, Google has auto-determined that I definitely want to read it in Spanish) I've noticed that there are sometimes inconsistencies and even omitted bits of important information, which can and should be reported.
[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#:%7E:text=custom%20auth%20claims)'s where I found the information specifying that it was a custom field.

Let me know if this helps or if more clarification is needed.